# jQuery / Javascript - How do I convert a pixel value (20px) to a number value (20)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know jQuery has a helper method for parsing unit strings into numbers. What is the jQuery method to do this?

```
var a = "20px";
var b = 20;
var c = $.parseMethod(a) + b;
```

Comment: parseInt(a, 10); return NaN if *a* is a string

Answer (score 244, accepted):

No jQuery required for this, [Plain Ol' JS (tm)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will do ya,

```
parseInt(a, 10);
```

Comment: Everyday in everyway Im loving you more and more javascript

Comment: @lsiden: it does work. `parseInt("20em", 10) === 20` and `parseInt("20pt", 10) === 20`.  Feel free to paste either expression into your favourite browser's console, or see [this very short example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Rqz4/).  Whatever problem you're having lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: A sidenote, the `parseInt` function will actually disregard any non-integer characters appended to the end of a string of integer characters. `parseInt('234sdfsdf') == 234`

Comment: @AndyE: Isiden was saying that parseInt won't convert em values (or pt or others) in the equivalent pixel values, which is what some people may need.

Answer (score 50):

More generally, `parseFloat` will process floating-point numbers correctly, whereas `parseInt` may silently lose significant digits:

```
parseFloat('20.954544px')
> 20.954544
parseInt('20.954544px')
> 20
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$.parseMethod = function (s)
{
    return Number(s.replace(/px$/, ''));
};
```

although how is this related to jQuery, I don't know

Answer (score 8):

```
 var c = parseInt(a,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the digging up, but:

```
var bar = "16px";

var foo = parseInt(bar, 10); // Doesn't work! Output is always 16px
// and
var foo = Number(s.replace(/px$/, '')); // No more!
```

Comment: parseInt('16px', 10); do work for me in Google Chrome dev console

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){<br>
    $("#btnW1").click(function(){<br>
        $("#d1").animate({<br>
            width: "+=" + x,

        });
    });
```

When trying to identify the variable x with a pixel value I by using jquery I put the += in quotes. Instead of having width: '+= x', which doesn't work because it thinks that x is a string rather than a number. Hopefully this helps.