# How can i get the position of a specific string in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, position, uilabel, uitextview, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [finding location of specific characters in UILabel on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191049/finding-location-of-specific-characters-in-uilabel-on-iphone)

How can i get the position of a specific string/substring in UILabel ?
The UILabel is a multiline label and also has /n characters.
Ultimately I should be able to draw another view in place of the position retrieved.

If not UILabel, could a UITextView be used to achieve results as expected above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191049/finding-location-of-specific-characters-in-uilabel-on-iphone

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you in building logic for the same..

```
@interface NSString ( containsCategory )
- (BOOL) containsString: (NSString*) substring;
@end

// - - - - 

@implementation NSString ( containsCategory )

- (BOOL) containsString: (NSString*) substring
{    
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString : substring];
    BOOL found = ( range.location != NSNotFound );
    return found;
}

@end
```

Comment: All you need to do is to pass the label.text to the string and rest will do take care by this code.

Comment: how your answer will ask the question???