# UILabel text on iPad not resizing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, size, uilabel

I have iOS 4.3 installed on my iPad.  I'm noticing that my text in my UILabels is not resizing.  In other words, I'm adding letters, but it's just truncating.  Same settings work find on iPhone also running 4.3.  I'm perplexed.  I've made certain that "Adjust to fit" is checked on the label properties.  I've even set it in the code with .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth and even tried calling sizeToFit.

None of these let the text resize.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Any ideas?

My next solution is going to use this:  [Check if label is truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077109/how-to-check-if-uilabel-is-truncated)  to try and manually resize the label text.

Comment: It's hard to tell why it's not working if you're not providing any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `CGSize eLabelSize = [yourLabel.text sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font];` to get the size of the label and then you can simply modify the yourLabel.frame.size property with eLabelSize.

This worked for me in case of iPhone.

Hope this works for you if yes do communicate..... :)

Comment: I am thinking of using this elsewhere.  Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.  I'm using OHAttributedLabel.  I had intended to do some things with color in my labels and have not yet gotten around to it.  It finally dawned on me that was the only difference from previous iPad versions and from the iPhone version (I never even thought to look at the class).  Turns out this OHAttributedLabel class does not support resizing yet.

Sorry for wasting everyones time.  Maybe someone else will someday find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it only appears as if the label is truncating text because the label frame runs out of the bounds of its parent view, which clips to its bounds? **Verify the frame** of the label and the **autoresizing mask**.

Also, the `minimumFontSize` property is set low enough?

Comment: Yes, the minimumFontSize was set to 18.  The font starting size was 36.