# React native - Fade out end of text label strings that don't fit (instead of truncate)

Tags: ios, react-native

How can I achieve this in react-native ?

Example in native iOS:

- [Fade the end of a label text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365330/fade-the-end-of-a-label-text)
- [Fade out end of text label strings that don't fit (instead of truncate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154313/fade-out-end-of-text-label-strings-that-dont-fit-instead-of-truncate)

Thanks!