# iOS:UILabel, how to judge UILabel's content overflow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

As the title, I wanna to judge a `UILabel` is completely show its content.
Such as, if I set the `UILabel` `numberOfLines` to be 2,maybe its content can arrive its end,maybe not,how can I judge that?

Comment: you can use sizeToFit property of UILabel and make number of Line = 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if UILabel is truncated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077109/how-to-check-if-uilabel-is-truncated)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077109/how-to-check-if-uilabel-is-truncated/24508153#24508153

Answer (score 0):

My code will help you

```
titleLable.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
[titleLable sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Maybe I give a misunderstand information, I mean if the UILabel cannot contains the content, return NO,if not return YES.

Comment: You can also change to numberOfLines to 0,it means you can give number of line content than display label content properly

Comment: U did not understand my meaning,I just want to know is a label (which is fixed frame)is can contain all its content ?

Comment: Yes,label contain all its content