# Swift ios how to find out Label text is truncated or not

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uilabel, truncate

**Label number of lines to 3 from storyboard**

Following is my code to find out label text is truncated or not

```
 let size = reviewLbl.text?.size(withAttributes: [.font: reviewLbl.font]) ?? .zero
    if (size.height > reviewLbl.frame.size.height) {

    }
```

**Also tried following link but it isn't working for me so don't call this as duplicate question**

[How to check if UILabel is truncated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077109/how-to-check-if-uilabel-is-truncated)

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: want to show read more if truncated

Comment: @amodkanthe have you tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43002072/3683408?

Comment: @Ram tried returns true even if it is not truncated

Comment: @amodkanthe have you check all the comments on this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3077143/3683408? Check and try with Fadi Abuzant comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  func countLabelLines() -> Int {
    // Call self.layoutIfNeeded() if your view is uses auto layout
    let myText = self.text! as NSString
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : self.font]

    let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], context: nil)
    return Int(ceil(CGFloat(labelSize.height) / self.font.lineHeight))
}
  func isTruncatedOrNot() -> Bool {

    if (self.countLabelLines() > self.numberOfLines) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

try this, and **self.bound.width** is your label width so if you added Label in stack view make sure label width or stackview have proper constraints.
In your case its returning true every time because it might have constraints issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this extension:

```
extension UILabel {

    var isTruncated: Bool {
        guard let labelText = text else { return false }

        let labelTextSize = (labelText as NSString).boundingRect(
            with: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [.font: font],
            context: nil).size

        return labelTextSize.height > bounds.size.height
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
if myLabel.isTruncated {
   // Show more
}
```

Comment: returns true even if it is not truncated