# How do I determine what font is being used (by default) in the UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol, uifont, ios15

There are a dozen answers to how to set the font of a `UISegmentedControl`, but I want to determine what font is being used, without having been manually set.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let s = segmentedControl.state // normal
    let ta1 = segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes(for: .normal) // nil
    let ta2 = UISegmentedControl.appearance().titleTextAttributes(for: .normal) // nil
}
```

Apple's API documentation is of no insight.

*The ultimate purpose is to use the font to calculate the size of the string, and compare to the segment size (if I can get that) and determine if the title is being truncated. Similar to [How do I check if UILabel is truncated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077109/how-to-check-if-uilabel-is-truncated)*

Comment: You should be able to get the font from the `UILabel`s of one of the segments by enumerating the `subviews` of the `SegmentedControl`.

Comment: i could not access the `UILabel` instances within the segments (i should add that detail when I have time.)

Comment: I've posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the font from one of the `UILabel` instances used to create the `UISegmentedControl` doing the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
...
  let font = segmentedControl.subviews(ofType: UILabel.self).first?.font
...
}
```

Here's the definition of `subviews`

```
extension UIView {
  
  func subviews<T>(ofType type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    var views: [T] = self.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? T }
    for view in self.subviews {
      views.append(contentsOf: view.subviews(ofType: type))
    }
    return views
  }
}
```